# issue in using soap webservice iphone

Tags: iphone, soap

> I am using the soap web-service in my application. i have a method
>   which will give me the user-setting of the User.In request i have to
>   pass the token and acknowledgment when i call with fixed token and
>   acknowledgment the response will be ok but when i call the web-service
>   second or third the response will be like this.

and this is my SOAP response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>Cannot use object of type stdClass as array</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

for that what i have to do?Is this my fault or fault in web-service?

thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

This is your fault, as indicated by the , the web service method is expecting something else than the type stdClass. I would recommend taking a good look at the .wsdl file to see the expected parameters.

Additionally I think this will prove very useful: [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/)

Comment: another recommendation : www.sudzc.com

Answer (score 0):

> use this method in the parserDidEndDocument:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the faultstring: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Probably you are sending the wrong parameters.

Comment: This method i am calling with the same parameter will give me the output but in the second and third call of this WS gives me this message.